# SQL server cannot be connected

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4.1, c#-5.0, sql-server-2012-express

I am developing an Asp.net MVC4 application wherein i am using SimpleMemberShip provider for authorization and i am using database MSSQL Server 2012 on the same machine.
When i openup the SQL server management studio and connect to the database by using windows authentication and sql server authentication, in both ways it is getting connected.

But when i am specifying the connection string in the application with correct credentials,
Still the application is unable to connect to the database.

I have restarted the system but it did not resolve the issue.

I have opened the configuration tool of SQl server and enabled TCP\IP and namepipe client protocols for sql client as well as for the server  and restarted all the sql server related services.

But still issue is remaining, i am sure about connection string it is 100% correct.
I am scratching my head from past 5 hrs but could not track down the issue.

Please tell me the possible solutions.

Comment: I trust you, but could you provide your connectionstring please?

Comment: How do you know with 100% certainty that your connection string is correct? What did you do to verify?

Comment: <add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data source=YOGESHS;Initial Catalog=1234;user id=sa;password=passward;" /> connection string is as above

Comment: @miky i connected to the database using c# app  from differnt machine with the same connectionstring

Comment: did you actually name your dB `1234`?

Comment: SimpleMemberShip provider use "DefaultConnection" ? i think you can see it in initialyser

Comment: @ miky not its with the some other name

Comment: @joan i could not understand what you are saying, yes simple membership provider uses default connectin and it is using this but not getting connected

Comment: I say it because in simpleMembershipInitialyzer there is this line:
 WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

and DefaultConnection is the name of connectionstring

Comment: @ Jaon, exactly the same line is being used in my code for my app
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);

Comment: Okay and where is located your connection string?, i say it because I answered a question where the user writed connection string in app.config in dll and it's doesn't work

Comment: @Jaon, simplemembership provider use this string for connecting to database and initializing the database with required tables.
So, is there anything wrong in it . the app is crashing out on the same line

Comment: @Jaon, this connection string is in the web.config of the Asp.MVC4 internet application and app is picking up the connection string
BECAUSE it is giving exception that unable to connect to database server which i have specified in the connection string

Comment: Have you looked in the errorlog on the SQL server?  Is it showing login failed or access denied on a database etc?  If there are no errors, it is likely that the application just cannot find the server, what exact error do you get in the app?

Comment: s it showing login failed or access denied on a database etc

Answer (score 0):

I would check firewall. If you have firewall (either default windows or using some AV) then temporarily disable it and see if it works.